# Unidirectional ManyToOne: Why transient instance saved with CascadeType.ALL but not CascadeType.PERSIST

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, cascade, hibernate-cascade

I am getting `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: safu.Publisher` exception when I try to run the following code:

```
public class SafuClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

            Publisher publisher = new Publisher("ABC", "ABC Co.");
            Book book = new Book("1-932394-88-5", "Safu", publisher);

            session.save(book);        

            session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

---

I have a Many-to-One relationship from Book to Publisher. Book and Publisher entities follows:

---

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="publisher_id")
    private Publisher publisher;    

    public Book() {}
    public Book(String isbn, String name, Publisher publisher) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.name = name;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Publisher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Publisher() {}
    public Publisher(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

---

If I replace `@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})` with `@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})` in the `Book` entity everything works just fine.

Could somebody explain why is it happening?

Comment: I too came across this exact error before, but have n't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `session.persist(book);` this solves the problem instead of `session.save(book);`

Answer (score 1):

The `session.save(book)` method works by removing the cascade attribute (`cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}`) from `@ManyToOne` annotation in the `Book` entity and adding the `@Cascade (value=CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)` on the publisher field instead.

The `@Cascade (value=CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)` uses Hibernate's native annotations.

---

Follows the updated Book.java that worked:

---

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="publisher_id")
    @Cascade(value=CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Publisher publisher;    

    public Book() {}
    public Book(String isbn, String name) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public Book(String isbn, String name, Publisher publisher) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.name = name;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }   
}
```